# Error mapping doctrine on OneToOne bidirectional relation

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, mapping

I'm trying to create an entity that is connected with another entity 1:1. The whole point is that Equip has to have an Estadi, and just one. I can update the schema correctly, the database is okay, but on the webpage debugger appears a mapping error.

> The association AppBundle\Entity\Equip#estadi refers to the inverse
>   side field AppBundle\Entity\Estadi#nom which is not defined as
>   association.
>
> The association AppBundle\Entity\Equip#estadi refers to the inverse
>   side field AppBundle\Entity\Estadi#nom which does not exist

This is entity Estadi:

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="estadis")
*/

class Estadi{
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=30)
    * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Equip",mappedBy="estadi",cascade={"persist"})
    * @ORM\Id
    */
    protected $nom;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    */
    protected $aforament;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    */
    protected $num_portes;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=50)
    */
    protected $direccio;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=4)
    */
    protected $any_construccio;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=30)
    */
    protected $nom_aficio;
}
```

This is Entity Equip:

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="equips")
*/

class Equip{
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=30)      
    * @ORM\Id
    */
    protected $nom;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    */
    protected $punts_lliga;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    */
    protected $num_jugadors;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Estadi",inversedBy="nom")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="nom_estadi",referencedColumnName="nom",onDelete="SET NULL")
    */
    protected $estadi;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Entrenador",inversedBy="nom")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="nom_entrenador",referencedColumnName="nom",onDelete="SET NULL")
    */      
    protected $entrenador;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Lliga",inversedBy="equips")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="nom_lliga",referencedColumnName="nom",onDelete="SET NULL")
    */
    protected $lliga;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Jugador",mappedBy="nom_equip")
    */
    protected $jugadors;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->jugadors = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define the `@OneToOne` annotation, it should not be on your primary key. Either the owning entity should contain a single association (unidirectional), or each entity should contain an association to the other - as entities, not connected to a primary key.

Your `Equip` mapping should instead look like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Estadi", inversedBy="equip")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="nom_estadi", referencedColumnName="nom")
 */
protected $estadi;

public function setEstadi(Estadi $estadi)
{
    $this->estadi = $estadi;

    return $this;
}

public function getEstadi()
{
    return $this->estadi;
}
```

Your `Estadi` mapping should instead look like this:

```
/**
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Equip", mappedBy="estadi")
 */
protected $equip;

public function getEquip(Equip $equip)
{
    return $this->equip;
}
```

I removed the `cascade` and `onDelete`, because if you're handling everything through Doctrine it should handle that for you automatically, but you still might have a use for them.  I also only put the setter on the owning entity from the way you described, but you could put it back on your `Estadi` entity as well - that's up to you.

Comment: I'll try it and tell u how did it go! Thank you very much!